# How to change CSS display property using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having problem about changing CSS display property to "none" using javascript

Here is my code:

```
<div class="mydiv" onClick="clickDiv1()">hello</div>
<div class="mydiv" onClick="clickDiv2()">hi</div>
<div class="mydiv" onClick="clickDiv3()">goodbye</div>
```

And here is my script:

```
 function clickDiv1() { 
alert('You clicked the first div!');
document.getElementByClassName('mydiv').style.display="none";
}

 function clickDiv2() {
alert('You clicked the second div!');
document.getElementByClassName('mydiv').style.display="none";
}

 function clickDiv3() {
alert('You clicked the second div!');
document.getElementByClassName('mydiv').style.display="none";
}
```

What I wanted is, different div alert different text when click on it, but when click on any div all div is invisible.

When I click on my div, the alert is execute but style doesn't change.

Why it doesn't work? Please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

The difference is when you use class to `document.getElementByClassName('mydiv')`, it returns you an array. So you need to use `document.getElementByClassName('mydiv')[i]`, where `i` is the array index. But `document.getElementById('div3')` will give you only one item.

```
document.getElementByClassName('mydiv')[0].style.display="none";
```

or

```
document.getElementById('div3').style.display="none";
```

should work.

Comment: Not exactly an *array*, but a live *nodeList*, which is an array-like object containing all the matched elements.

Comment: document.getElement**s**ByClassName('mydiv') rather than
document.getElementByClassName('mydiv')

Answer (score 0):

The correct Javascript method to use to select HTML elements is `getElementsByClassName()`.

This will return an array of all the elements in the DOM with that class name, which you need to loop through and individually set the display to `none`.

For your example, this code would work:

```
function hideAll() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('mydiv');
  for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    var elem = elems[i];
    elem.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function clickDiv1() {
  alert('You clicked the first div!');
  hideAll();
}

function clickDiv2() {
  alert('You clicked the second div!');
  hideAll();
}

function clickDiv3() {
  alert('You clicked the third div!');
  hideAll();
}
```

Comment: That will only hide which one you click, I wanted to hide **ALL** divs.

Comment: Sorry about that, I misunderstood your question. I've updated my answer and it should work for you now.